# Argumenting IntelliJ IDEA's maven build process

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

We have setup bamboo CI tool for our project and we let bamboo to take control of the source code versioning. Thus we don't hardcode the version number into our `pom.xml` file, instead we use the property `${version}` as a placeholder in that file:

xml

```
<groupId>my.group</groupId>
<artifactId>my-artifact</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>${version}</version>
<name>outbound</name>
```

Bamboo will invoke maven as `mvn package -Dversion=x.y.z` when it building the project. If we want to manually build the project in our local dev environment we follow the same approach by giving it any arbitrary version number on command line.

Now the problem is IntelliJ IDEA doesn't look like recognise this change and it just can't build the project because it failed to download dependencies specified in `pom.xml` file.

Anyone got the experience on dealing with this situation?

Thanks... Green

Comment: Use the maven version plugin instead. Set the version to a SNAPSHOT so that you always have the same number when building locally. On the build server you can set a version instead of the snapshot. See https://axelfontaine.com/blog/final-nail.html

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum. We will try maven version plugin in the next project. However it is unlike to change the current one in short time because it is managed by customer. Any idea about the intellij idea stuff?

Comment: Try providing a default with `<properties>` see https://axelfontaine.com/blog/dead-burried.html

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this with your particular configuration, but in IntelliJ IDEA's Settings / Build, Execution, Deployment / Build Tools / Maven / Runner, you can specify "Properties", which IDEA provides to Maven whenever it runs. If you set your "version" property there, I would expect that IDEA would use it whenever running Maven, both for its internal purposes to download dependencies and when you are running the application.

[image: Screenshot of Settings / Build, Execution, Deployment / Build Tools / Maven / Runner]